# 405 on Exporting CSV file in django

Tags: python, django, csv, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to export some data to downloadable csv file. When I click "Export" button on my website everything works up to a point when I get `405` response. The `post` method works as expected, in `response` I see all expected data. The filtering ptocess below works as expected as well.

Here is the view class:

```
class ExportInvoicesToCsvView(View, IsSuperuserMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post', 'get']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = (
            'attachment; filename=raport.csv'
        )

        writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';')

        filters = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf8'))
        data = Data.objects.filter(filters)

        writer.writerow([
            'data.a', 'data.b', 'data.c', 'data.d', 'data.e'
        ])


        return response
```

The url config is as follows:

```
url(
        r'^invoices-csv/$',
        ExportInvoicesToCsvView.as_view(),
        name='invoices-csv'
    ),
```

And html template:

```
<a  href="{% url 'accountant:bills:invoices-csv' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
    ng-click="getSelected()">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o fa-2x pull-left"></i>
    &nbsp;{% trans 'Exportuj do csv' %}
</a>
```

**EDIT**
Here is console log.

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /accountant/bills/invoices-csv/
[27/Oct/2017 16:41:12] "GET /accountant/bills/invoices-csv/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
[27/Oct/2017 16:41:15] "POST /accountant/bills/invoices-csv/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

As I can see there is some sort of problem with methods used. nonetheless I am able to step into the `post` method and get data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need `http_method_names`. Generally speaking, Django views will only process requests for HTTP verbs if a corresponding method exists in the view class. So, since your view has a `post`, method, that's enough to tell Django that this view handles `POST` requests.

A 405 response means `Method Not Allowed`.

It doesn't look like your template is making a `POST` request. Without seeing the `getSelected()` function, I can't know for certain, but I'd guess that you're not actually making a `POST`; you're making a `GET`, and since your view doesn't implement a `get()` method, you're seeing the 405 response.

Try the following:

- remove the `http_method_names`
- make sure you're actually making a POST request from your template (use your browser's developer tools to inspect the network request).

Comment: I've changed `post` to `get` and it started to work more or less (I get 405 on POST this time) but I'm albe to download the file. I'll investigate it further.

Comment: Then that's proof that you're not making a `POST` request from your template. Your `<a>` tag is just a link to the view (`GET`). Ask yourself; why do I need `POST`?

Comment: It's for changing data on server as far as I remember. True, it should be only GET.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need quotes around the filename part of your `Content-Disposition` definition. This:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = (
        'attachment; filename=raport.csv'
    )
```

Should be this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = (
        'attachment; filename="raport.csv"'
    )
```

Comment: It seems there were 2 problems with my code. I can accept only 1 answer but I'm giving this an upvote since it also helped.